# How to convert email as a blob in Gmail Addon Using Card Services

Tags: google-apps-script, blob, gmail-api, add-on, utility

My aim to convert an email's content, with attachments, into a binary large object (blob) format within the Gmail add-on. I'm getting the body content using the below function but I'm not able to convert it into blob format.

I referred to the following documents but I don't know which function I have to use here for blob format.

> 1. [Blob](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob)
> 2. [GmailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app)

```
function loadAddon(event){
    var accessToken = event.gmail.accessToken;
    var messageId = event.gmail.messageId;
    GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);
    var mailMessage = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);
    var emailContent = mailMessage.getBody();
    console.log("Email Content: " + emailContent);
}
```

Can anyone guide me on this?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, how about putting a script of `var blob = Utilities.newBlob(mailMessage.getRawContent())` after the line of `var mailMessage = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);`? Unfortunately, I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question. So, I posted it as a comment. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can we convert blob in **.eml** format?

Comment: About your additional question of `Thank you for your answer. Can we convert blob in .eml format?`, in this case, please use `var blob = Utilities.newBlob(mailMessage.getRawContent(), "message/rfc822", "sampleFilename.eml")`. By the way, was my guess for your question correct?

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike. You can add your answer so that can be useful for others also.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. And, I posted it as an answer. Please confirm it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create a blob of the eml format, please modify the script as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function loadAddon(event) {
  var accessToken = event.gmail.accessToken;
  var messageId = event.gmail.messageId;
  GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);
  var mailMessage = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);
  var emailContent = mailMessage.getBody();
  console.log("Email Content: " + emailContent);

  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(mailMessage.getRawContent(), "message/rfc822", "sampleFilename.eml");
}
```

- In this modification, a blob of eml format can be obtained by `Utilities.newBlob(mailMessage.getRawContent(), "message/rfc822", "sampleFilename.eml")`.

#### Reference:

- [newBlob(data, contentType, name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#newblobdata,-contenttype,-name_1)